# Using ito isometry to calculate variance

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Define a stochastic process $(\Phi (t): t\in [0,4])$ by $$\Phi (t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
2, & \mbox{if $t\in[0,1]$} \\
W(1), & \mbox{if $t\in(1,2]$} \\
W(1.5), & \mbox{if $t\in(2,3]$} \\
0, & \mbox{if $t\in(3,4]$}
\end{array}
\right.$$
where W is brownian motion.

I am trying to calculate Variance of the stochastic integral $\int_0^4 \Phi (t) dW(t) $.

Knowing that the expectation of the stochastic integral is 0
$Var(\int_0^4 \Phi (t) dW(t)) = E[(\int_0^4 \Phi (t) dW(t))^2]$

Using Ito Isometry,
$E[(\int_0^4 \Phi (t) dW(t))^2] = E[(\int_0^4 \Phi^2 (t) dW(t)]$

So finally, I get
$Var(\int_0^4 \Phi (t) dW(t))= E[4W(1) + W^2(1)(W(2)-W(1)) + W^2(1.5)(W(3)-W(2))]$

I haven't been able to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Ito isometry states that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t (\phi_s d W_s)^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \phi_s^2 ds\right]
\end{align}
That is, the integral on the right contains $ds$ rather than $dW_s$. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry). So then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t \phi_s^2 ds\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[2^2+W_1^2+W_{3/2}^2+0^2\right]
\end{align}